# Syntax error in len(sys.argv)

Tags: python

Python interpreter gives Syntax error while running below code:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
  a=sys.argv[1]
  b=sys.argv[2]
  sum=int(a) + int(b)
  print "The sum is: ", sum
elif len(sys.argv) != 3:
  print "Only two arguments allowed !"
else:
  print "Please enter two numbers as argument with the script. Try again !"
```

Error:

```
luckee@zarvis:~/python$ ./sumtwo.py 5 10
./sumtwo.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `sys.argv'
./sumtwo.py: line 3: `if len(sys.argv) == 3:'
```

Comment: Your file is interpreted by your shell, not Python interpreter. Try `python sumtwo.py` or adding `#!python` as a first file of your file.

Comment: Rogalski's got it.  Also this is somewhat tangential, but your `if` and `elif` clauses cover every possibilty - len(sys.argv) has to be either == 3 or != 3.  The else will never get triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is interpreted by your shell, not Python interpreter. Try specifying binary when running it:

```
luckee@zarvis:~/python$ python sumtwo.py 5 10
```

Alternatively, you may add [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as a first line of your script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
  a=sys.argv[1]
  b=sys.argv[2]
  sum=int(a) + int(b)
  print "The sum is: ", sum
elif len(sys.argv) != 3:
  print "Only two arguments allowed !"
else:
  print "Please enter two numbers as argument with the script. Try again !"
```